# Avoiding Google Tag Manager blocking by AdBlockers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have used Amplitude analytics in the past in my react Web app to send event data. However I just started with Google Tag Manager and noticed it does not run because being blocked by adBlockers. Amplitude was always functional because I loaded their Javascript SDK through `NPM install 'github:amplitude/Amplitude-Javascript'` and initialized it at app load with client API key. I like the approach of Google Tag manager where I dont have redeploy app to make changes to my analytics logic. How can I take a similar approach to  avoiding being blocked by adblockers.

It may very well be that Google products are popular so Adblock specifically just block google analytics products not other analytics products.

Comment: `Amplitude was always functional`

Just because the lib loaded, doesn't mean it was functional. Ad blockers were likely still blocking actually API requests to amplitude's servers.

Answer (score 11):

You don't. If people don't want to be tracked, that is their decision. You should not be forcing people to provide you with any data they do not want to provide. Especially by using some shady "bypassing" measures. Instead-

You could use a cookie to permanently disable your tracking of those who do not wish to be tracked, to help you preserve reliable analytics. See: http://www.multiminds.eu/2016/05/19/how-to-disable-tracking-via-google-tag-manager/

Or, better yet, simply measure the percentage of visitors who have disabled tracking so your analytical data can remain accurate. See: https://marthijnhoiting.com/detect-if-someone-is-blocking-google-analytics-or-google-tag-manager/

Comment: But that's not necessarily what this is about. For example, I don't care about "user X" per say. I don't want to know who YOU are or what YOU are doing on my site, I just want to know how many users are on my site or keep track of page views (not linked to a user, but in general), which pages/sections are most valuable/accessed etc.
Plus, adblocks should be about ads and annoying popups, not about analytics. It's in the name "adblock", it's not called "analytics block" or "track block". That's misleading :)

Comment: Anyway, I am working on a solution. Will post an answer if it pans out (it should)

Comment: Finding this also an annoying issue for an Cloud Application we host. Is it not possible to just download and include that JS into your project as a local .JS file ?

Comment: Thats a rubbish answer. Users being tracked 24/7 on any website, so no extension will help you out. Some websites track even your mouse moves and then they replay the actions etc. With google analytics you might just want to know if any users are hitting your website, how many, what devices is mainly used (so you could alter the website if for example 98% of users are using phone and your website is not phone friendly) and so on. I have GA myself and I dont allow google to use any of my collected data. Its just for the basic understanding of your users for the web improvement

Comment: Also its fair to point out that if you are on my property. I can track you.

Comment: However google tag manager doesn't have to be used for tracking only. For example, it can be used to inject many additional features, chatbox etc.

Comment: The stupidity of your answer is just amazing. You do understand that blocked Google Tag Manager does not only affect tracking services? Its not only used for that. Its like shutting down the power grid in your neighbour so you will not get see advertisement. Blocking analytics != blocking google tag manager.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible.
You can use reverse proxy for Google Tag Manager.

1. First, download the Google Analytics JavaScript library itself and host it on your server.
2. Then alter the code in the downloaded library to change the target host from [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) to your own domain name using find-replace.
3. Replace the link from the default Google Analytics script in your codebase to modified one.
4. Create a proxy endpoint to Google Analytics servers on your back end. One important step here is to additionally detect the client’s IP address and write it explicitly in requests to Google Analytics servers to preserve correct location detection.
   Test the results. You’re done!

more detail info on [freecodecamp.org/news/save-your-analytics-from-content-blockers](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/save-your-analytics-from-content-blockers-7ee08c6ec7ee/)  and https://analytics-bypassing-adblockers.netlify.com

Answer (score 1):

There's [dataunlocker.com](https://dataunlocker.com) as well as some other open source alternatives ([1](https://github.com/dataunlocker/save-analytics-from-content-blockers), [2](https://github.com/blaumedia/go-gtm-ga-proxy)) which can help to fix reporting accuracy of Google Tag Manager, Amplitude, Google Analytics etc.

Talking about ethics and privacy, tools like DataUnlocker are just tools which allow you to bypass ad blockers as if you have implemented server-side analytics. I think by correctly implementing that "we use cookies" consent one can solve any privacy concerns.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to get around some blockers with the following in a node app:

```
var request = require('request');

app.get('/proxy*', function(req,res) {

  const newurl = req.url.split('/proxy/')[1];
  const data = request(newurl);
  //data.on('response', function(response){console.log(JSON.stringify(response))});
  data.pipe(res);

});
```

Then in your snippets for GTM prepend: "/proxy/" in the url and now the call goes via your server.

The caveat with the above is that without additional code you can't preview the container, but the container does load correctly. Lack of preview is a different issue to deal with.